# Hibernate entity modification/deletion invalidates query cache involing same entity name?

Tags: hibernate, caching, ehcache, query-cache

I read from some blogs that

> The timestamp cache keeps track of the last update timestamp for each
>   table (this timestamp is updated for any table modification). If query
>   caching is on, there is exactly one timestamp cache and it is utilized
>   by all query cache instances. Any time the query cache is checked for
>   a query, the timestamp cache is checked for all tables in the query.
>   If the timestamp of the last update on a table is greater than the
>   time the query results were cached, then the entry is removed and the
>   lookup is a miss.

Let's say I loaded entity using `get()` method and saved it by calling `saveOrUpdate()` (OR) I deleted the entity by calling `delete()`.

**In all these cases timestamp cache keeps track of the table that has been modified and let query cache invalidate it's any cached query results of those tables?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's what is meant by the blog entry you pasted.